# Newbie to KVM/oVirt/ovs looking for clarity

Tags: linux, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, openvswitch, ovirt

I have some experience with vSphere, but am looking to get up and running with KVM.  I've been looking at using oVirt as a VCenter type manager but, being new to all things server/Linux/virtualisation, I'm a bit unclear on a couple of things:

1. Does installing oVirt on a Fedora server install KVM also, or would I need to pre-install KVM?
2. To add another Host, would I just install KVM, and add it to the oVirt engine, in the same way I would install ESXi and add it to vCenter?
3. I'm interested in learning more about OpenvSwitch, is this installed with the oVirt installation or will I need to install seperately?

I don't know if I'm missing something obvious reading up about it online or if this knowledge is assumed? Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. ovirt-engine, the controller node doesn't need KVM. ovirt hosts will
   install KVM and other packages, when added to the setup
2. Just set up a minimal Linux server and add it via the GUI, everything will be bootstrapped
3. OVS doesn't come with ovirt, ovirt uses Linux bridges by default.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I think I need to install it and get see it in action for myself.